# Loop only executing first statement

Tags: javascript, loops, infinite-loop, do-while

I'm practicing with loops and I thought I'd make it fun with a simple battlesim. I'm not sure why but the doBattle loop only calls battleMenu without ever alerting anything else. What am I missing/misunderstanding? Any recommendations on improving the code are welcome.

```
doBattle(player, goblin_01);

function battleMenu(){
        selection = prompt("\n Battle menu\n1: Attack\n2: Defend\n3: Abilities\n4: Status\n5: Enemy Status\n Enter a choice: ");
        // Checks for valid input
        while (selection > 5 || selection < 1){
            selection = prompt("Invalid choice.\n Enter a choice(1-5)");
        }
}

function doBattle(x,y){
    do { battleMenu();
        switch(selection){
            case 1: // do stuff
                break;
            case 2: // do other stuff
                break;
            case 3: // alternative stuff
                        break; 
            case 4: // not stuff but things
                break;
            case 5: // something irrelevant to the topic
                break;
                } // End of Selection Switch

            } while // condition that became false

    }
```

EDIT: As was first commented in the OP, by Ian, the problem was that I was passing a String but testing for integers. I forgot to convert types and that even numbers are entered as strings. The cases made the code convoluted and I'm assuming that's why it's on-hold. But hopefully now it's of use.

Comment: I think you should try to refactor this big loop.

Comment: `selection` holds a string, while you're using `case` with **numbers**. Either change your switch/case to use strings, or convert the `prompt` return value to a number

Comment: Putting a `+` right in front of your `prompt`s "fixes" it: http://jsfiddle.net/3m9Qb/ - there's still more work to do on the code though

Comment: Thank you Ian! That was it. I completely forgot to convert the string to a number!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is the `dataType` of `selection` variable . The variable `selection` is treated as `String` but in the `switch` statement you are using `Integer` `dataType` for comparison. So you could use `dataType` conversion method to get `Integer` value ...

```
    var m=parseInt(selection);
      switch(m){
      ............
      ............
```

And here is the working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zew6h/)

Answer (score -1):

It appears your selection variable is not defined or passed to doBattle.   try declaring the variable at the top of your code where you declare player and goblin_01 Objects

Comment: I tried that. It isn't the problem, I didn't include it for the sake of brevity (There's alot more around this code but it's mostly unrelated).